# How to dynamically populate created by and updated by filed in domain object while persisting to DB using hibernate and spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I have few domain object(User,Address,Post,etc..) in my application, when my application is persisting these domain object into DB , I need to get the logged in user name and populate my domain object's created by user or updated by user filed.user name is available across all my controllers.App is using spring mvc and hibernate frameworks.Can any one explain how to accomplish this by using spring AOP or hibernate interceptor.(Spring AOP is preferred :) ).
Ex:

```
Class ParentDomain{
  String createdByUser;
  String updatedByUser;
 }

Class Address extends ParentDomain{
 String street;
 String city;
 }

Class Post extends ParentDomain{
 String title;
 String content;
 }
```

when I'm persisting Address or Post object into DB , i need to dynamically populate createdBy or updatedBy fields with logged in user name which is available in session and across all the controllers.